# Display Spreadsheet data in Sites with Html Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I  displaying 
What I want to do with similar to this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/advanced-examples/create-table-from-sheet-data) but instead of using UI Services to display the table, I would like to use HTML Services. Someone from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950027/displaying-google-spreadsheets-data-in-google-sites-as-html) mentioned that you could use Templated HTML to display Spreadsheet data in html. Could anyone elaborated on this topic? A simple example like [this](https://script.google.com/a/dakota-consulting.com/d/1i65oG_ymE1lreHtB6WBGaPHi3oLD_-wPd5Ter1nsN7maFAWgUA9DbE4C/edit) would very helpful because I'd like to see a demonstration on it works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple example of using templated HTML to display a table from spreadsheet data available in the documentation, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-templates).

I've published [a running copy](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw-mIJwOiYb9vX-47JRqJFk3IyLOJjANPYZPo-APzmtUBeu3E3O/exec), utilizing the same data from Waqar's tutorial, for an easy comparison. The source [spreadsheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvF9FEyqXFxAdEplRHp5dGc4Q1E3OXMyV2s4RktiQWc#gid=0), as is the script. (Edit: script is also provided below.)

#### Code.gs

```js
// All code in this script is copied from
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-templates

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('0AvF9FEyqXFxAdEplRHp5dGc4Q1E3OXMyV2s4RktiQWc')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<table border='1px solid black'>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! An 8 year old post and it's exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you!