# Google App Script Web App not loading data (sometimes)

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a Google Script Web App, which automatically generates an index, taking the data from a spreadsheet.

I am currently running into a problem loading the Web App. From time to time the data within the drop-down menus is not loading. This usually happens when drop-downs are opened quickly, as soon as they are loaded.
I guess this occurs because a dropdown is displayed before the data obtained from the spreadsheet has been loaded into it, causing the loading of the data within the drop-downs to be "canceled".

I would like to know if anyone has a solution or knows why this happens since mine is only an assumption.

**My GS Code:**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index1');
}

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auto-Index");
const sectionsLenghtData = ss.getRange("E1").getValue();
const sectionsLenght = "A1:B"+sectionsLenghtData;

const procedLenghtData = ss.getRange("E2").getValue();
const procedLenght = "H1:N"+procedLenghtData;

//READS THE PHONE BRANDS
function readProcedSections() {
    var data = ss.getRange(sectionsLenght).getValues();
    Logger.log(data)
    return data
}

//READS THE PHONES
function readProcedData() {
    var data = ss.getRange(procedLenght).getValues();
    Logger.log(data)
    return data
}
```

**The Data read with the GS is loaded to this HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

    <title>BIND - Procedimientos y Políticas</title>
    <style>
        body {
          margin-left: 1rem;
          margin-right: 1rem;
        }

        #loadingDiv {
          background-color: #fff;
          position: fixed;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          z-index: 1000;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }

        #pills-load {
          height: 30px;
          width: 100px;
        }

        #loadingSpinner {
        }

        .navbar {
          background-color: #fff;
          padding-top: 1rem;
          position: sticky;
          top:0;
          width:100%;
          z-index:100;
        }

        .accordion-button:hover {
          color: #0d6efd;
        }

        .search {
          float: float;
          width: 25%;
          margin-left: 1rem;
        }

        #lupa {
          margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
        }

        .nav {
          float: left;
          width: 73%;
        }

        .nav-link {
          color: #343a40;
        }

        .nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
          font-weight: 600;
          color: #0d6efd;
        }

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        
        .accordion {
            margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
            margin-left:0.5rem;
            margin-right: 0.5rem;
        }
        
        a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
        }

        n1 {

        }

        .n2 {
            font-size: 0.97rem;
        }

        .n3 {
          font-size: 0.97rem;
        }

        .n4 {
          font-size: 0.97rem;
        }

        .proced {
          display: flex;
        }

        .material-icons {
          margin-left: 0.8rem;
          height: 1rem;
          width: 1rem;
          color: #343a40;
          
        }

        .material-icons:hover {
          color:#0d6efd;
        }

        .sinHijos .material-icons {
          display: none;
        }

        .cardn1 {
          margin-left: 2.6rem;
        }

        .cardn2 {
          margin-left: 2.6rem;
        }

        .cardn3 {
          margin-left: 5.2rem;
        }

        .cardn4 {
          margin-left: 7.8rem;
        }

        #listPoliticas {
          margin-left: 1rem;
        }

        #index {
          margin-top: 0.4rem;
        }
        

    </style>
    <script>
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar">

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-proced" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-proced" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-proced" aria-selected="true" onclick="showHideProcedimientos()">Procedimientos</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button class="nav-link" id="pills-polit" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-polit" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-polit" aria-selected="false" onclick="showHidePoliticas()">Políticas</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="search">
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" id="inputsearch" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Buscar">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="searchbutton" type="submit">
            <svg id="lupa" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
</svg>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="index">

    </div>

    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="politicas" style="display: none;">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <li id="listPoliticas">

        </li>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>

      function getProcedSections(values) {
          var x = document.getElementById("index");
          values.forEach(function(item) {
          //x.innerHTML += '<h2 id="'+ item[1] +'">'+ item[0] +'</h2>';
          x.innerHTML += '<div class="accordion-item"><h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-heading"><button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapse'+item[1]+'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapse'+item[1]+'">'+ item[0] + '</button></h2><div id="flush-collapse'+item[1]+'" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-heading'+item[1]+'" data-bs-parent="#index"><div class="accordion-body" id="'+item[1]+'"></div></div></div>'
          });
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getProcedSections).readProcedSections();

        
        function getProcedData(values) {
          var x = document.getElementById("index");
          values.forEach(function(item) {
          var y = document.getElementById(item[4]);
          y.innerHTML += '<div class="proced '+item[6]+'"><a class="'+ item[3] +' link" href="'+item[2]+'" target="_blank">'+ item[1] +'</a><a class="material-icons" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#'+item[5]+'" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse'+item[5]+'">keyboard_arrow_down</a></div><div class="collapse card card-body card'+item[3]+'" id="'+item[5]+'"></div>'
          });
          return;
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getProcedData).readProcedData();

        function showHidePoliticas(){
          document.getElementById("index").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("politicas").style.display="inline";
        }

        function showHideProcedimientos() {
          document.getElementById("politicas").style.display="none";
          document.getElementById("index").style.display="inline"
        }

    </script>



    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to the Web App and the Spreadsheet.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz37hctjTKMHodsQh0JKqutxTsbasUj9WRRRxBNEtCb1nGoXm5GbZGKxg/exec

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-bKLOHzCOTx0E6LMR06h8qpNH8vxKVTBVz3srHVY_qQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to make calls to the Spreadsheet Service in the global scope because every time that a function is called by a simple trigger like `doGet`, by `google.script.run` etc. those calls are being executed.

By the other hand since you need that your dropdowns options be available as soon as they are shown, it might be better that instead of reading the dropdown options after the dropdowns were loaded to do it before that.

There are several ways to to do this. One way is to use [templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) instead of serving the HTML immediately.

If you don't want to learn yet to use templated HTML you might improve the performance of your web app by using a single call to server side call to retrieve all the values that you need.

Related

- [Display Spreadsheet data in Sites with Html Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16660906/1595451)